# How can I redirect an entire sub-directory and its contents to the same directory in another domain using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, directory-structure

How can I redirect an entire sub-directory and its contents to the same directory in another domain using .htaccess?

For example, all files here:

```
www.olddomain.com/directory1
```

Automatically 301 redirect to:

```
www.newdomain.com/directory1
```

So...

```
www.olddomain.com/directory1 -> www.olddomain.com/directory1

www.olddomain.com/directory1/file1.php -> www.newdomain.com/directory1/file1.php

www.olddomain.com/directory1/directory2/file2.php -> www.newdomain.com/directory1/directory2/file2.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have tagged this question with ".htaccess", so I assume that you are using the Apache web server.

You can do the redirection with mod_rewrite. Please read over its [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) and the [rewrite guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html), especially the latter.

The following two lines in your virtual host configuration for olddomain.com should work. They could even work on a .htaccess file inside the root directory of olddomain.com, if you have set the rights accordingly (approximately `AllowOverride All`).

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule   ^directory1(.*)          http://www.newdomain.com/directory1$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: I would also add the [R=301] at the end of the rule, but otherwise this will work fine

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry, I forgot, default is HTTP 302. I'll just edit that in. Thank you.